# What does operator > and < mean when going with std::cout?

Tags: c++, operators, cout

```
int var;
int *p = &var;

std::cout > var; //invalid
std::cout > p; //valid

std::cout < var; //invalid
std::cout < p; //valid
```

I know it seems make no meaning but what is the actually meaning of `>` and `<` in this case and why it's only valid when the right-hand operand is pointer ?

I'm using Visual Studio.

Comment: What is your compiler?

Comment: @EdgarRokyan I'm using Visual Studio for this.

Comment: Are you referring to '<' or '<<'(viceversa '>' or '>>')

Comment: I can't reproduce this in [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9f0eb33f99b2750), [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c703b36d9e887c99), or [MSVC](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/). Which version on Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @ShankarShastri he mean `<` and `>` obviously

Comment: [This stream operator overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) might help explain the issue.

Comment: @TartanLlama 2010 Express

Comment: @TartanLlama if it is a VS compiler bug, I will remember it forever.

Comment: Same thing, just a different operator.

Comment: If you use `<` with a pointer then the compiler (successfully) tries to casts the `std::out` to a pointer. It's the same as `a==1;` where a might be of any type that can be converted to `int`. Of course, both are meaningless and harmless statements.  But the compiler is not able to convert the `std::cout` to the integer `var`. Posting the actual error message would be really appreciated.

Comment: Seems that @JoachimPileborg has answered the question posting the appropriate link. So the `std::cout` casts implicitly to `void*` bacause of `operator void*() const` and compared with `int*` successfully.

Comment: It's illegal since C++11. No cast from `std::ostream` to `void *` any more. It's using explicit bool conversion now `explicit operator bool() const;`

Comment: @Carousel Yep, but OP uses C++ 98/03.